# how to save output of tokenized string into list and compare that list with dictionary keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, output, nltk

a string of text is tokenized and i want to save the outoput x into the list . so i can comopare that list with dictionary keys 
. but i am unable to save the output into list . 
I tried many things, i can compare pre defined list to dictionary but i want to save the output of token string into list . my code is :

```
from  nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize,word_tokenize

string=input("enter your text: ? ") # I am megan , hello word
x= (word_tokenize(string))
print(x)  # now this can be used to compare with dictioonary

x=[]

champ_ids=x

champ_dict = {"hello" : 0, "Carly" : 36, "Freddy" : 85, "Megan" : 14, "Dilbert" : 69}

for k, v in champ_dict.items():
    if v in champ_ids:
        print(k)       # output hello, megan
```

Comment: why do you reset x to empty list ? `x=[]`, if you want x as a list, use `x=list(x)`

Comment: i am confused . as how i can save output x as list  named champ_ids ?

Comment: Please update your question with expected input and output.

Comment: As of now champ_ids = word_tokenize(string) would be enough I guess. You can directly save into champ_ids because word_tokenize returns a list.

Comment: And moreover, I'm pretty sure word_tokenize returns a list of string, then your comparison in the loop should be `if k in champ_ids`

Comment: its not working Mufeed . I tried it , the output of string aftr tokenize could not compared. at least i m unable to do so , can u look into code ?

Comment: it returns the tokenized output of string , i want to save that output into the list .

Comment: Can you edit the question with sample input and expected output? @Rida

Comment: edited , u can check in code , i wrote input and output i want , but plz focus on  the problm , i wana save output x into list named champ_ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your use case,I tried to solve it based on your input and output.

```
from  nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize,word_tokenize
string=input("enter your text: ? ")
champ_ids = (word_tokenize(string))
champ_dict = {"hello" : 0, "Carly" : 36, "Freddy" : 85, "Megan" : 14, 
 "Dilbert" : 69}

result = ""
value = 0

for k,v in champ_dict.items():
    if k in champ_ids:
        result += k+" "
        value += v

if value in range(20,30):
    status = "high"
elif value in range(10,20):
    status = "moderate"
elif value in range(0,10):
    status = "low"

print("result = ", result)
print("value = ", value)
print("status = ", status)
```

**Output**:

```
result =  hello Megan 
value =  14
status =  moderate
```

Comment: thanks Mufeed . it worked for me . can i add the key of the output k ?

Comment: Can you explain me what you mean by add?

Comment: You want output be hello, megan(seperated by comma)?

Comment: champ_dict = {"hello" : 0, "Carly" : 36, "Freddy" : 85, "Megan" : 14, "Dilbert" : 69}
here key :  hello has a value 0 and key megan has a value 14  . i want to add these values on the basis of input. like value of hello and megan added up and print on the basis of high value , low value and moderate value , high value should be printed if result is 30 , low value oprinted if result limit is o to 10, moderate limit printed if result is 10 to 20 ?

Comment: Now according to your description it should print something like 14, moderate?

Comment: if values of matched words are 14 after adding up . matched words in our case are hello and megan . with values 0 and 14 , 0+14 =14 , so it should print moderate .

Comment: Thank you so much dear Mufeed . (y)

Answer (score 0):

I think your are not enough familiar with the concepts you are working with like lists, dictionaries and so.

variable x is redondant with champ_ids, so we can directly use `champ_ids = word_tokenize(string)`. Don't put parenthesis every where as it can have a special meaning in python (tuples, generators...).

after this line, `champ_ids` is a list containing words.
Now if you want to print the words in `champ_dict` that appears in `champ_ids`, you must compare with the keys of your dict, not the values:

```
for k, _ in champ_dict.items():
    if k in champ_ids:
        print(k)
```

OR

```
for k in champ_dict.keys():
    if k in champ_ids:
        print(k)
```